# what is restcall,pathcall,namedcall in lagom.javadsl.api.Descriptor;

Tags: akka, akka-http, lagom

I am new to microservices and Lagom framework, in the service api where we make ServiceCalls I do not understand the difference of *`namedcall`*, *`pathcall`* and *`restcall`*. where and when should we use which?

for instance in these calls:

```
  ServiceCall<NotUsed, Cargo, Done> register();
  restCall(Method.POST, "/api/registration", register()

  ServiceCall<NotUsed, NotUsed, Source<Cargo, ?>> getLiveRegistrations();
  pathCall("/api/registration/live", getLiveRegistrations())

  ServiceCall<User, NotUsed> createUser();
  namedCall("/api/users", this::createUser)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  [Lagom Documentation](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.1.x/java/ServiceDescriptors.html) covers it pretty well:

1. Named

> The simplest type of identifier is a name, and by default, that name is set to be the same name as the name of the method on the interface that implements it. A custom name can also be supplied, by passing it to the namedCall method:

```
default Descriptor descriptor() {
    return named("hello").withCalls(
        namedCall("hello", this::sayHello)
    );
}
```

> In this case, we’ve named it hello, instead of the default of sayHello. When implemented using REST, this will mean this call will have a path of /hello.

2. Path

> The second type of identifier is a path based identifier. This uses a URI path and query string to route calls, and from it dynamic path parameters can optionally be extracted out. They can be configured using the pathCall method.
>
> Dynamic path parameters are extracted from the path by declaring dynamic parts in the path. These are prefixed with a colon, for example, a path of /order/:id has a dynamic part called id. Lagom will extract this parameter from the path, and pass it to the service call method.

```
ServiceCall<NotUsed, Order> getOrder(long id);

default Descriptor descriptor() {
    return named("orders").withCalls(
        pathCall("/order/:id", this::getOrder)
    );
}
```

> Multiple parameters can of course be extracted out, these will be passed to your service call method in the order they are extracted from the URL:

3. Rest Call

The final type of identifier is a REST identifier. REST identifiers are designed to be used when creating semantic REST APIs. They use both a path, as with the path based identifier, and a request method, to identify them. They can be configured using the restCall method:

```
ServiceCall<Item, NotUsed> addItem(long orderId);
ServiceCall<NotUsed, Item> getItem(long orderId, String itemId);
ServiceCall<NotUsed, NotUsed> deleteItem(long orderId, String itemId);

default Descriptor descriptor() {
return named("orders").withCalls(
        restCall(Method.POST,   "/order/:orderId/item",         this::addItem),
        restCall(Method.GET,    "/order/:orderId/item/:itemId", this::getItem),
        restCall(Method.DELETE, "/order/:orderId/item/:itemId", this::deleteItem)
);
}
```